# Filter results from YouTube data API based on date

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to filter data from YouTube data API (using commentThreads).

Goal here is to get all the comments published for the channel after 2018-03-25. I have tried different date formats and it looks like the filter is not working as I get all the results back.

Any ideas?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCU34OIeAyiD4BaDwihx5QpQ&key=xxxx&maxResults=100&publishedAfter=2018-03-25T13:15:30Z

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take at tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I too found the same issue. Have u solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Youtube google api, but assuming that this is the API reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

It doesn't mention the `publishedAfter`-option, which leads me to believe that it doesn't exist?

This probably means that you'll need to use the `order` option along with `maxResults` to achieve your goal.

Comment: I was looking at generic options for List and it looks like it has publishedAfter. I don't get any error when I use publishedAfter but looks like it ignores this parameter.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: It shouldn't be ignored for `.../youtube/v3/search/list`, but it will be ignored for `.../youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list`.